# Creating Dynamic URLs - JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am working on a project that allows people to list phones for sale and be able to view all phones for sale. I have this working correctly. The viewPhones.jsp is returning a list of all phones with all their details. E.g Brand, Model, Network, Storage, Colour, ScreenSize etc.

The issue is that it needs to be set up so that you only see the 'Brand' and 'Model' (for example 'iPhone' '6') and then be able to tap 'more info' to see the rest of the details. This 'more info' button should open a new jsp with the full details of the phone.

I am not sure how to create URLs for each of these 'more info' .jsp's.

Here is the output I currently have:

[viewPhones.jsp output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Dnt.png)
This is done using just a normal toString method in the phone.java class

Each phone has a phoneID in the database so I'm assuming I would use this in some way? I'm just lost as to how to do it.

Apologies if I haven't given enough information, if any code snippets are needed I will add them to the post.

```html
<%@page import="java.util.Collection"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Arrays"%>
<%@page import="phoneauction.Phone"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            Phone p = new Phone();

            Collection<Phone> list = p.findAllPhones();

            out.println(list);

        %>
        <br><br>
        <h3> Enter the Phone ID of the phone you want to add to your favourites </h3>        
        <form action="favouritedPhone.jsp">
            Phone ID: <input type="text" name="favourite">
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Favourites">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way....

```
//favouritedPhone.jsp file

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
String favName = request.getString("favourite");
//favName is the string that you input in viewPhone.jsp
            Phone p = new Phone();
//add farourite list and show detail data.
            ...

        %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Ajax instead of creating new jsp file for each moreinfo button because that will be more fast and better approach. Whenevr user will click any button request will be send in background and response will be disolayed. Refer this link to see more details about http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/

You could also use JQuery here where you can create toggle method in this case you have to preloaded all the data to be  displayed you can visit this link for an example of how you can use toggle method http://javacrunch.in/Project.jsp click on any project name for observing how t works.

Hope this solve your query